# map an interface inside struct filed into a postgres db column datatype

Tags: postgresql, go

I have a struct in which one of the fields type is interface , how can i map the interface into a db field (what should be the column type)so that i can retrive that? In the below code i want to know how to map the Task field inside database so that i can store "a" and "b" in database. If it wasn't an interface i could have mapped with underlying struct . I don't have any constraints in postgres package to be used

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Sai struct {
    Name string. // can map this in db as string
    Task Test.  // how should i map this
}
type Test interface {
    Print()
}
type dummyStruct1 struct {
    Name StringStruct
}

type StringStruct struct {
    Name string
}
type dummyStruct2 struct {
    Name StringStruct
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")

    s1 := dummyStruct1{Name: StringStruct{"jon"}}
    s2 := dummyStruct1{Name: StringStruct{"smith"}}

    a := Sai{Name: "task1", Task: s1.Hello()}
    b := Sai{Name: "task1", Task: s2.Hello()}
    a.Task.Print()
    b.Task.Print()

}
func (s StringStruct) Print() {
    fmt.Println(s.Name)
}
func (d dummyStruct1) Hello() StringStruct {
    return d.Name
}
func (d dummyStruct2) Hello() StringStruct {
    return d.Name
}
```

Comment: What's the target column's type?

Comment: that's the answer i am looking for

Comment: what's the column type to be stored in database , who underlying value is a interface, let me know if i have to refactor the question, suggestions to refactor the question is open as well :)

Comment: You'll need to choose a type that can be used to represent *every* type that implements the `Test` interface type. With PostgreSQL you can use `jsonb`, `text`, `bytea`, etc. The hard part though is to implement the conversion from the Go type to the Pg type and back. That implementation will depend on what the potential Go types are and what the Pg column type you decided upon is.

Comment: can you show me a postgres schema example? just for the above

Answer (score 0):

If you are the one implementing the concrete types for interface `Test`:

If you can modify `Test` itself do:

```
import (
  "database/sql"
  "database/sql/driver"
)
// other stuff
type Test interface{
  sql.Scanner
  driver.Valuer
  Print()
}
```

else create a new type `TestDB`

```
import (
  "database/sql"
  "database/sql/driver"
)
// other stuff
type TestDB interface{
  sql.Scanner
  driver.Valuer
  Test
}
```

now whichever new type you create will have to implement the [sql.Scanner](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Scanner) and [driver.Valuer](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql/driver#Valuer) interfaces. These are used automatically by `lib/pq` internally when writing value to or scanning data from the database.

As an example

```
// Assuming Test can implement Valuer and Scanner interfaces
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "database/sql"
    "database/sql/driver"
)

type Sai struct {
    Name string // can map this in db as string
    Task Test  // how should i map this
}
type Test interface {
    sql.Scanner
    driver.Valuer
    Print()
}

type StringStruct struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {
    ...
}

func (s StringStruct) Print() {
    fmt.Println(s.Name)
}

func (s StringStruct) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return s.Name
}

func (s *StringStruct) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    v, ok := src.(string)
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("not a string")
    }
    s.Name = v
}

// more code
...
...
```

Now you can store anything of type `StringStruct` - which is also of type `Test` - as a simple `varchar` or `text` inside postgres. This is also not limited to `string`s only though as you can tell - infact this is my current method of storing and retrieving json from pq.